# Estimate the conditional probability given contaminated output?

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, censoring

I have a dataset with exam grades and for each student an indicator variable that is equal to $y=1$ if the student was cribbing and $y=0$ otherwise. As a result of the crib the grade is expected to be larger than the true level of knowledge by this student. There are also some input parameters that are believed to affect both the level of knowledge and the probability of a crib by a particular student.

There is a hidden variable - a "true level of knowledge" or a "true grade" that I would like to estimate. When $y=0$ this true knowledge is estimated by the achieved grade. When $y=1$ there has to be some influence of the crib on the grade that I want to measure given the input parameters.

The typical input parameters I will have would be the homework grades during the semester and observed crib during the semester plus some general input like the highschool grades, biometrics etc.

How to build such a regression?

P.S. This is just a toy problem mathematically identical to a real world problem I have. No student was harmed :)